# Multiple full houses odds in texas hold'em at a table of 8?

Tags: full-house

What are the odds of two players both getting full houses in texas hold'em at a table of 8?

Comment: Are you happy to assume all players go to showdown? If not, we'd need to approximate the probability of a player reaching a showdown (or reaching each a board state where a boat is possible and meshing this with the odds of making a boat at that board state).

Comment: If the board is not paired then zero.

Comment: @Paparazzi by that token, if there are quads or a straight flush on the board, then zero also, although that last one is redundant with what you said.

Answer (score 1):

Board needs to be paired to even have a chance

```
49.9%  one pair 
 7.62% two pair 
 2.87% trips
60.39% total
```

For just one player board one pair on the board the chance of a full house is about 3.3%

For the next player that would go down as if one player has a full house then some of the outs are gone - 2.6%

For the 3rd more outs are gone - 1.8%.

2 on a paired board with 8 players like 2.6%
But I am not sure about that number

3 on a paired board with 8 players like 0.09%
But I am not sure about that number

You would need to run a simulation for the actual answer

These are not independent events so simple 1-((1-%)^8) type statistics don't work